# Python Inventory management using item ids

Tags: python

I've been making a textadventure for a while now. I made an variable called inventory that holds all currently owned items... Now I wanted to make an developer command that allows you to add items to the inventory, in order to add them I use the items id. Every item in the game has an id and a name. So to create items I use a class that creates them like following:

```
class item:
    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.type = "item"
```

So my items are created like this:

```
housekey = bp.item("housekey", 1)
keycard = bp.item("keycard", 2)
```

my inventory is just a variable that looks like that:

```
inventory = []
```

Items are stored as objects in this list by now.

***So, how can I add those items to my inventory using their ids...***

*Thank you already :D*

Comment: Do you mean something like `inventory.append(housekey)` and `inventory.append(keycard)`? I'm not quite sure what you're asking...

Answer (score 1):

I can help you by providing a basic logic used to build an inventory system:

```
class item:

    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.type = "item"

class Inventory:

    def __init__(self,name): # No whatter what params
        self.name = name
        self.items = [] # Initialize empty array of items

    def add_item(itm):
        if type(itm) is not item: # A small and smart verification
            raise TypeError("Invalid item")
        self.items.append(itm) # Adding items to the inventory
```

The implementation will be as follow:

```
equipements_inventory = Inventory("equipements")

sword = item(name="sword",id=1)
equipements_inventory.add_item(sword)

shiled = item(name="shiled ",id=2)
equipements_inventory.add_item(shiled)
...
...
```

Then, you can find any information about any item like this:

```
for itm in equipements_inventory.items:
    print(itm.name)
    print(itm.id)
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionaries :

```
inventory = {}
inventory[id] = name
```